# Set up kafka-connect on local in Ubuntu to use with debezium and WSO2 stream processor?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

This is a newbie question but i am not able to figure out how to install **kafka-connect** on my local machine ubuntu 18.04 to use it with **debezium**. I already have kafkaz zoopeeker and wso2 stream processor working fine but for **kafka-connect** i am facing bottleneck. We could use confluent for it but i don't want to use confluent here. I want to have separate components. Once i get kafka connect installed locally i can follow the instructions on debezium tutorial on their web-site to install **mongodb connector plugin**.

If you have any link or source for this **kafka-connect** set please ping.

Comment: "i don't want to use confluent here" -> why not?

Comment: Confluent Platform isn't "one component". It is separate. You could install it via apt, even

Comment: I don't want to use confluent because i have my previous set up in kafka and don't want to change it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connect_running) details how to run Kafka Connect. Specifically:

```
bin/connect-standalone.sh config/connect-standalone.properties connector1.properties
```

You'll need to [install Debezium](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/0.10/install.html) too, before launching the Kafka Connect worker.

For more background info on Kafka Connect see http://rmoff.dev/ksldn19-kafka-connect.

Comment: Can we limit the amount of data we retrieve in connector properties as debezium looks for cdc in data source and according to my understanding it's for entire database and i couldn't find a way to limit few specific collections.

Comment: Please post a new question since this is not directly related to your original question about installation.